# Prove that if $7$ divides $6^n + 1$ then $n$ is odd

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that if $7$ divides $6^n + 1$ then $n$ is odd

Attempt:

We'll prove the contrapositive: $n$  is not odd if $7$ does not divide $6^n + 1$

Comment: Just to note: You have written the inverse, not the contrapositive.  The contrapositive would be "If $n$ is not odd, then $7$ does not divide $6^n + 1$."

Comment: Similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584686/prove-using-mathematical-induction-that-23n-1-is-divisible-by-7 but different.

Answer (score 8):

If $x+1$ divides $x^n+1$ then $-1$ is a root of $x^n+1$. Therefore $(-1)^n+1=0$ which is only possible if $n$ is odd. Now put $x=6$.

Comment: Ah!! Simple... elegant.. Great Job :)

Answer (score 4):

Try to look at...:

$$(7-1)^n+1$$

Comment: Best of all! +1

Answer (score 1):

As $6\equiv-1\pmod7$

$\implies 6^{2m+1}\equiv(-1)^{2m+1}\equiv-1$

and $6^{2m}\equiv(-1)^{2m}\equiv1$

Comment: This proves that if $n$ is odd, then $7 | 6^n + 1$.  It doesn't prove that if $n$ is not odd, $7 \not | 6^n + 1$, although it could by the same mechanism.

Comment: @DanielV, please find the edited version

Answer (score 1):

$$6^{2k} + 1 \equiv 36^k + 1 \equiv 1^k + 1 \equiv 2 \not \equiv 0 \pmod 7$$

Answer (score 1):

More generally, $a-b\mid a^n-b^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, $a,b\in\mathbb Z$. As a consequence, $a+b\mid a^n+b^n$ if $n$ is odd.